# how to get the actual url in php while all pages are routing through index.php in MVC frameworks

Tags: php

When routing, all the php scripts request_uri showing only index.php.

I want to find the actual uri instead of index.php.

So,is there any php functions or variables that helps in getting the actual url.

I know they are different ways of getting the url for different frameworks but i want to know solution that works for every framework

Comment: Are you using a public MVC framework? If so, which?

Comment: i am using laravel

Comment: have you checked middlewares ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you stated that you are using laravel, the solution below only works for this particular framework.

```
$current = url()->current(); // Returns the current url
```

If you need to pass parameters, getting the name of the route and building the url based on it works fine:

```
$current = URL::action(Route::currentRouteName(), ['arg' => 'value']); // Returns the current url and assign arguments to it
```

Comment: your answer is little helpfull but i want to know the internal working of that function and is there any way that is possible with php functions rather than framework related functions